# Rearrange the array based on priority

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

There are objects of `Person` class like: M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,W1,W2,W3,W4,C1,C2. Where M: Man, W: Woman, C: Child

They are stored in the array below:

```
Person[] arr = {M1,M3,C1,W1,W3,M2,M4,W2,C2,W4,M5};
```

Now the array has to be rearranged based on a priority set for each type of objects. Priorites are given in a Enum:

```
enum Priority{
    One,
    Two,
    Three;
}
```

Also make sure that the order remain same, for example: M1 should come before M2, M2 should come before M3 and so on...

**Input:** `Person[] arr = {M1,M3,C1,W1,W3,M2,M4,W2,C2,W4,M5};`
           and Priority for Man: Priority.Two
               Priority for Woman: Priority.One
               Priority for Child: Priority.Three

**Expected Output:** `Person[] arr = {W1,W2,W3,W4,M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,C1,C2};`

**Incorrect Output:** `Person[] arr = {W1,W3,W2,W4,M1,M5,M4,M3,M2,C2,C1};`

The latter is wrong, since order must also remain same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution using Comparator interface for sorting custom objects.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {

private int priority;
private String objName;

Person(String name,int value){
    this.objName = name;
    this.priority = value;
}

public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public String getObjName() {
    return objName;
}

public void setObjName(String objName) {
    this.objName = objName;
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person M1 = new Person("M1",Priority.valueOf("ONE").getValue());
    Person M2 = new Person("M2",Priority.valueOf("ONE").getValue());
    Person M3 = new Person("M3",Priority.valueOf("ONE").getValue());
    Person M4 = new Person("M4",Priority.valueOf("ONE").getValue());
    Person M5 = new Person("M5",Priority.valueOf("ONE").getValue());
    Person W1 = new Person("W1",Priority.valueOf("THREE").getValue());
    Person W2 = new Person("W2",Priority.valueOf("THREE").getValue());
    Person W3 = new Person("W3",Priority.valueOf("THREE").getValue());
    Person W4 = new Person("W4",Priority.valueOf("THREE").getValue());      
    Person C1 = new Person("C1",Priority.valueOf("TWO").getValue());
    Person C2 = new Person("C2",Priority.valueOf("TWO").getValue());

    Person[] arr = {M1,M3,C1,W1,W3,M2,M4,W2,C2,W4,M5};

    List<Person> list = Arrays.asList(arr);

    System.out.println("Before sort...");
    for(Person p : list){
        System.out.println(p.getObjName());
    }

    Collections.sort(list, new PersonComparator<Person>());

    System.out.println("After sort...");
    for(Person p : list){
        System.out.println(p.getObjName());
    }
}

}

enum Priority{  
ONE(1),TWO(2),THREE(3); 

private int value;  
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}   
Priority(int v){
    this.value = v;
}
}

class PersonComparator<T> implements Comparator<Person> {
public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    //Sorting based on priority
    int v1 = p1.getPriority();
    int v2 = p2.getPriority();
    ;
    if (v1 - v2 == 0) {
        //Sorting based on object name
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(p1.getObjName().substring(1, 2));
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(p2.getObjName().substring(1, 2));
        return i1 - i2;
    }
    return v1 - v2;
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot do this in this way. The objects are given in an array and you cannot modify the Person class. You only have Priority enum class  containing the priorities for each type of objects . Can you suggest any alternate way.

Comment: @RoyalTiger Glad, it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
    final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).mapToObj(i -> new Person("M" + i, Priority.TWO)).forEach(persons::add);
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).mapToObj(i -> new Person("W" + i, Priority.ONE)).forEach(persons::add);
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 2).mapToObj(i -> new Person("C" + i, Priority.THREE)).forEach(persons::add);
    persons.add(new Person("M11", Priority.TWO)); // test to sort by number
    List<Person> sorted = persons.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getPriority).thenComparingInt(p -> Integer.parseInt(p.getName().substring(1))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("Before sort " + persons.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println("After sort " + sorted.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

ouput

```
Before sort [M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, W1, W2, W3, W4, C1, C2, M11]
After sort [W1, W2, W3, W4, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M11, C1, C2]
```

please note: The values in enum are ordered, above code depends on the order of values in enum class

**Edit-1**

Compartor

```
    Comparator<Person> comp = new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
            int co = p1.getPriority().compareTo(p2.getPriority());
            if (co == 0)
                return Integer.parseInt(p1.getName().substring(1)) - Integer.parseInt(p2.getName().substring(1));
            return co;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Saravana, Can I do the same without using Stream .. I mean to to say what would be my solution before java8

Comment: @RoyalTiger I have added the `Comparator` you can use it in `Collections.sort` or `Arrays.sort`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to create your own comparator for the Person Class so your Person objects can be sorted in a collection using the Collections.sort() method.

Here is a link on how to go about making your own comparator for a Class
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Comment: I have rephrased the statement. Its has to be 'rearranged'.not 'sorted'. I think this word was misleading.